# Texmaker does not compile and generate pdfs - "Could not start command" error

Tags: pdftex, compilation-error

I have just downloaded on my personal computer the Texmaker editor.
It seems like it won't compile any tex file, giving the following error:

> Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1
> -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

I checked that the Miktex and Texmaker are installed on the same driver.
Moreover, the Texworks actually compiles pretty fine.
I wonder what should I do to make it work.

Comment: Have you added the system path to your PC? You may try `pdflatex --version` in the terminal to check that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I checked and the pdflatex path is Ok. That's probably a problem in the configurations of the Texmaker.